# Non injectively path-connected space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, path-connected

Do you have an example of a path-connected non-hausdorff space on which two points can't be injectively path-connected? (that is, any path between them is not injective). I tried to figure out what such a space should look like, and what its topological properties should be, but I failed.

Thank you very much,
AF

Comment: This search may be of interest: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Path%20Connected%2B~Arc%20connected

Comment: FYI: what you call "injectively path-connected" is usually called [arc connected](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000038).

Comment: @PatrickR: That is not true. An arc is a homeomorphic path. Consider the interval with the trivial topology: it is clearly injectively path-connected, but not arc-connected.

Comment: @tomasz That depends on how you define it.  Arc connected is defined as "injectively path-connected" in *Counterexamples in Topology* (Steen & Seebach) p. 29.  And I guess other sources use the stronger definition of "homeomorphic path".  What is the most common one?

Comment: @PatrickR: You're right! There seems to be some disagreement when it comes to terminology, although it seems that the outlier is Steen & Seebach. At the very least, Wikipedia, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Wolfram Mathworld do say that an arc is a homeomorphism from the interval or its image. As does Kuratowski, Engelking and Munkres. Bourbaki does not seem to say anything about it.

Comment: @tomasz Wolfram is not a good source.  But good to know about all the other ones.  Pi-base will have to be expanded to give the two versions probably.

Answer (score 5):

Sure. It's not a very interesting example, but here goes: take the indiscrete (a.k.a trivial) topology on any countable set. It is trivially path connected, since every function to it is continuous... but there are no injections $[0,1]\to F$ where $F$ is countable.

Comment: Thanks @FShrike. Is it possible on a metric space?

Comment: @ArthurFilippi No. It is a theorem that path-connected Hausdorff spaces (which includes all path connected metric spaces!) are arcwise connected, meaning in particular we can always *choose* an injective path. However this theorem is quite hard to prove

Comment: Thanks. I guess Zorn's lemma is necessary to construct arcs from paths?

Comment: @ArthurFilippi To be honest, I have never reviewed the proof (or even seen a reference to where it is proven). My guess is that it has nothing to do with Zorn's lemma but I could be wrong. The intuition for that guess is that Zorn is highly nonconstructive, highly arbitrary, highly "weird"; it is suspicious that we can expect a continuous function out of it, never mind a topological embedding [which is very 'regular'].

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I'm pretty sure that an arc can be constructed from a path as the limit of maximal shortcuts. The main point is that if the codomain is Hausdorff, then the set of singular arguments is closed, so there is a well-defined "first shortcut". The more delicate part is that you then need to continue these shortcuts (possibly) transfinitely, but all of this is well- (and uniquely) defined thanks to compactness and the linear order on $[0,1]$, so no choice is necessary.

Comment: @tomasz What do you mean by singular arguments? Elements $0\le t\le 1$ such that $f^{-1}\{f(t)\}$ has more than one element? I'm not convinced that these are closed. Of course, each fibre $f^{-1}\{f(t)\}$ is closed if the codomain is Hausdorff but the union of all these fibres need not be closed

Comment: @FShrike: Yes. They are the projection of the preimage of the diagonal via $\gamma\times \gamma$.

Comment: @tomasz ah right, that's a nice use of compactness. Interesting. How exactly does this shortcutting work, though? Consider the very first singular argument $t_0$. There need not be a first $t>t_0$ such that $t$ is also a singular argument, so for any subsegment I consider $[t_0, t_0+\delta)$ I might cross potentially infinitely many singular arguments, perhaps infinitely many singular arguments having the same value.

Comment: No, but there is the last $t>t_0$ such that $\gamma(t)=\gamma(t_0)$. This gives you the first shortcut. Yes, you may need to repeat this infinitely many times, passing to the limit (also maybe infinitely many times), but I think this checks out in the end. Did not check carefully though.

Comment: FYI, it's Corollary 31.6 in Willard.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the most natural example is the interval with a doubled endpoint. It is a (non-Hausdorff) path-connected compact smooth manifold, so it basically has all the nice properties you can imagine a space which is path-connected but not arc-connected can have, but it is not hard to see that there is no arc connecting the twin endpoints.

A more pathological (but still not trivial, as in FShrike's answer) example is the Sierpiński two-point space, i.e. $X=\{x,y\}$ where the open sets are $\emptyset, X, \{x\}$. Then the function $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to X$ given by $\gamma(1)=y$, $\gamma(t)=x$ for $t<1$ is a path, but clearly there is no injective path, since $X$ is finite.

Comment: I like your example. I contemplated instead the line with two origins but it doesn't work; this does

Comment: Why not? Line with two origins is also fine, it's just not compact.

Comment: Oh wait :) you're right. I was trying to connect the wrong points. Silly me.